# Datatables not displaying data (Laravel 8.4.x)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, datatables

**Hey there and thank you in advance.**
Before describing my problem, I want to clarify that I have searched up the issue on Google and read through several posts, of which none helped me fix my problem.

That is why I'm adressing my problem personally here.

So basically I'm trying to display the 'users' table via the User model through DataTables on my Laravel application. When loading the page, the data does not appear (see Screenshot 1).
[image: screenshot]

**View (Folder 'resources/views/verwaltung' File 'nutzer.blade.php')**

```
<head>
@extends('layouts.simple.master')
@section('title', 'Verwaltung - Nutzer')

@section('css')
@endsection

@section('style')
@endsection

@section('breadcrumb-title')
<h3>Nutzer</h3>
@endsection

@section('breadcrumb-items')
<li class="breadcrumb-item">Verwaltung</li>
<li class="breadcrumb-item active">Nutzer</li>
@endsection
<script src="{{ asset('assets/datatable/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}" ></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/datatable/datatable/datatables/datatable.custom.js') }}" ></script>
</head>

@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
         <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
               <h5>Verwaltung / Nutzer</h5>
               <span>Hier kannst du die Nutzer der Seite bearbeiten</span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
               <h2 class="mb-4">Nutzer</h2>
                    <table class="table table-bordered nutzerverwaltung">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Nickname</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Teamrank</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

@endsection

@section('script')
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    
    var table = $('.nutzerverwaltung').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: "{{ route('verwaltung.nutzer.list') }}",
        columns: [
            {data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex'},
            {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
            {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
            {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
            {data: 'teamrank', name: 'teamrank'},
            {
                data: 'action', 
                name: 'action', 
                orderable: true, 
                searchable: true
            },
        ]
    });
    
  });
</script>
@endsection
```

**Controller (Folder 'app/Http/Controllers' File 'UserController.php')**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use DataTables;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('verwaltung.nutzer');
    }


    public function getUsers(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $data = User::latest()->get();
            return Datatables::of($data)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                    $actionBtn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>';
                    return $actionBtn;
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action'])
                ->make(true);
        }
    }
}
```

**Routes (Folder 'routes' File 'web.php') - (just the relevant part)**

```
Route::get('verwaltung.nutzer', [UserController::class, 'index'])->name('verwaltung.nutzer');
Route::get('verwaltung.nutzer.list', [UserController::class, 'getUsers'])->name('verwaltung.nutzer.list');
```

**Model (Folder 'app/Models' File 'User.php')**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'teamrank',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: One thing I notice is that you have more columns defined in your JS datatables definition than you have in your HTML.  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Put you data url 'verwaltung.nutzer.list' in your address bar of your browser and see (or not) your data ... let's know

Comment: Answer to the first comment: I tried removing the first column in order to fix it but it didnt change it.

Comment: Answer to the second comment: Upon opening that link I just receive a blank page..

Comment: I suspect you have another issue as well.  I know DataTables pretty well, but not php or laravel.

Comment: try including <script src="{{ asset('assets/datatable/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}" ></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/datatable/datatable/datatables/datatable.custom.js') }}" ></script>
 in master layout or use push stack

Comment: @JohnLobo didn't help

Comment: @Jake.can you able to  show in any php sandbox env so we can see what exactly happening

Comment: @JohnLobo not sure how, if you would be so kind to explain it to me

Comment: https://phpsandbox.io/

Comment: Unless you want me to include all of my code in that sandbox, I wouldn't know how that would work. But if you do, thats not possible because of licensing issues.